# Keras next(); what does (2, 256, 128, 128, 3) mean

Tags: keras, image-preprocessing

I have used the next() method on a Keras generator. I then turned this into a numpy array to get the shape:

```
data = generator.next()
data = np.array(data)
print(data.shape)

>>> (2, 256, 128, 128, 3)
```

256 is my batch size, and (128, 128, 3) is my image size. But what does 2 represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Keras generator returns a Tuple for data and label. So is that 2.*

First you should unpack it with a tuple then use image and labels.

> *yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels*

```py
img, labels = traindata.next()
img.shape, labels.shape
```

**Output** - ((16, 224, 224, 3), (16, 2))

*We are also supposed to return a Tuple of batches of images/labels in case we build a custom generator for Keras*.